# Elvis Presley's pronunciation of 'dancing' in his "jailhouse rock" /'dæn(t)ɪn/

Tags: american-english, speech, phonology, phonetics

I'd like to know the IPA narrow transcription of his pronunciation of 'dancing' in "jailhouse rock", as well as what phonological process makes it possible. It seems like intrusive /t/ deletes the following /s/.

Comment: No intrusive t in dancing.

Comment: If by 'what phonological process makes it possible' you mean 'why it should be considered acceptable', note that song lyrics can bear such slight resemblance to standard English that they were (and perhaps still are) considered off-topic on ELU.

Comment: It is possible to pronounce "dancing" such that it sounds sort of like "dans-tin", especially when using an Elvis-like drawl.  Best I can explain it, the S sound is drug out slightly and then cut off abruptly, resulting in a percussive effect.  I can't play sounds very well on this box, so I haven't attempted to listen to this specific song.

Comment: @HotLicks That's exactly what I hear ['dɛ̞(ə)nɪn]

Comment: According to Wiktionary, _leggo_ is "Contraction of let's go", similarly dropping **/ts/**

Answer (score 2):

The IPA transcription would be something like [ˈdæːnsɪ̞n] since [there's **no** intrusive [t] in Elvis's pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj0Rz-uP4Mk). I'm not sure how you heard one.

Elvis stretches out the pronunciation of the /æ/ both to meet the rhythm of the song and as part of the Southern American tendency to lengthen ("drawl") vowels. The /ɪ/ in most dialects of American English is a little lower than 'normal'. The fronting of /ŋ/ to [n] in an unstressed syllable is common in English dialects around the world but particularly common in Southern American English.

As far as why you might hear an intrusive [t] when *you* sing "Jailhouse Rock", intrusive sounds in general are ***epenthesis*** (Greek for "also-putting-in") and inserting consonants in particular ***excrescence*** (Latin for "out-growing"). It could seem more comfortable to some speakers because it would give the tongue something to do ("bridge") between the two alveolar consonants /n/ & /s/.

Alternatively, some languages like Chinese have a separate /t͡s/ consonant (pinyin *c*) that can show up in situations like this. But, no, I don't think *anyone* is "dantin" the jailhouse rock.

Comment: I do not hear any /t/, but suppose it in theory to explain the reduction of /s/, which is why it's between parentheses (unconventional annotation of mine). Btw, in the phrase 'let's rock', I cannot perceive any /s/ whatsoever, so I'd like to know your opinion about it.

Comment: The /s/ in "let's rock" is present but reduced. There's nothing unusual about the /s/ in "dancin'" at all in the linked music video, though it's possible you're listening to a different recording and/or artist (e.g., [the Blues Brothers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjqlWbl69G8)) and confusing them with Elvis.

Comment: The same process is found for the word 'dancing' in  the song "One more time" by Daft Punk.